# backbone.js 'undefined' get request

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

This is my code:

```
$(function (){
var Slide = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        castid  :1,
        id      :1
    },
    urlRoot:  function(){
        return 'slidecasts/' + this.get("castid") + '/slides/';
    },
});


var SlideView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#presentation"),
    events: {
        'click #next': 'next',
        'click #previous': 'previous',
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'next');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.model.fetch();
        var variables = { 
            presentation_name: "This is a Slide-Number: ",
            slidenumber: "xxx",
            imageurl:  this.model.url() +"/"+ this.model.get('imageLinks'), 
            slide_content:  this.model.get("content")};
        var template = _.template( $("#slide_template").html(), variables );
        this.$el.html( template );
        return this;
    },
    next: function(){
        console.log(this.model.id);
        this.model.nextslide();
    },
    previous: function(){
        console.log("previous function in view");
    }
});

testslide = new Slide();
var slideView = new SlideView({model: testslide});

});
```

This works fine but in the debug console I always see a GET Request to "slidecasts/1/slides/1/undefined" which of course fails. I don't really understand where I trigger this get request.

**Edit - the template code**

```
<script type="text/template" id="slide_template">
  <label>Presentation <%= presentation_name %>  </label> <br/>
  <img src="<%= imageurl %>" id="slide_pic" /> <br/>
  <textarea id="slide_content">
    <%= slide_content %>
  </textarea>
  <div id="next">next slide </div>
  <div id="previous">previous slide </div>  
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an asynchronous problem.

This is the sequence of events:

1. You call `this.model.fetch()` to populate the model.
2. You say `variables.imageurl = this.model.url() + '/' + this.model.get('imageLinks')`.
3. The (asynchronous) `fetch` hasn't returned yet so `this.model.get('imageLinks')` is `undefined`.
4. You build the HTML and use `this.$el.html(template)` to update the page.
5. The browser renders your HTML using the incorrect `imageurl` from **2**.
6. A bad GET request is logged because of **5**.
7. The `fetch` from **1** returns from the server and triggers a `'change'` event.
8. The `'change'` event triggers a new call to `render`.
9. This `render` call has a fully populated `this.model` so `variables.imageurl` is correct and the HTML comes out right this time.

If you let the `fetch` trigger the `render` then the problem will go away:

```
initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'next');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    this.model.fetch();
},
render: function() {
    // As before except no this.model.fetch()
}
```

Comment: thanks. very good answer, works now. one thing i don't understand: how is the render function triggered now. is render called by fetch automatically? I would have guessed something like fetch(){success: render()}

Comment: @Nicolas: You `this.model.bind('change', this.render);` and `this.model.fetch()` will trigger a `'change'` event and that triggers the `render` call.

Answer (score 1):

How I can't see the *template* you are using I'm just guessing here:

The problem is in this line:

```
this.model.url() +"/"+ this.model.get('imageLinks'),
```

Your *template* is trying to define an `<img>` element with such URL but the `imageLinks` attribute is *undefined*.

Comment: Try to `console.log` the `variables` hash, and the `template` variable that is storing the compiled template... I still think the problem is in the `imageurl` URL.

Comment: @muistooshort Actually I did read it, but I didn't thought in the _asynchronous_ behavior of it :/

Comment: That just means that you haven't made that mistake enough times yourself :) You were right about where the `undefined` came from though.